# Android sdk- Get remote XML content

Tags: android, xml

I´m trying to get the remote `xml` content on my Android Application using the code:

```
URL aUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)aUrl.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);  // timeout for reading the google maps data: 15 secs
conn.connect();...
```

When I try to `connect()` I'm getting the exception:

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException  (id=830019595736)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same inside a thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() { 
                         // the same
                  }).start();
```

of course `AsyncTask` is also a way to go

Answer (score 0):

From [the exception java doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) it says you can't do HTML connection from your main thread. You should use a service or similar for work that might take a long time to execute or you will end up with an ANR.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it all: you are trying to do network communication on the UI (main) thread. As you might guess the solution is to run the download on a separate thread. The easiest and probably best way to do it is to use an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).